# how to create marketo sandbox account for developement purpose for writing and testing API

Tags: marketo

I am new in marketo.

I have to write API to integrate marketo in my web application but it says it requires token Id to make any API call in marketo and token will be provided if you login in marketo but problem is that I am new to marketo and I don't have Marketo login credential.

Is there any way to create test account in marketo so that I can create one and write my API and test it there.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please help me on integration of Marketo into my Web Application created in visual studio MVC Dot Net.

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply for a partner account which gives you a sandbox account here:

[Partner webpage](https://www.marketo.com/why-marketo/partners/programs/technology/)

There appear to be minimum requirements to be eligible however. Where I work we have a partner account and an internal deployment for our marketing team, and I have found the sandbox partner account severely limited compared to a real deployment.